# Python ValueError: Invalid literal for int () with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.6

I keep getting this error in line 87: " words[w][0]+=(int(word[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is any help would be appreciated.

```
#get a word from the user to analyze
word=str.lower(input("Enter a word to test: "))

#open up all of the movie reviews
file=open("movie_reviews.txt","r")

alldata=str.lower(file.read())

file.close()

#create accumulators
total=0
numreviews=0

#split data into a list
splitreviews=alldata.split("\n")


#iterate over each review
for review in splitreviews:

    #further split the review into individual words

    words=review.split(" ")

    if word in words:

        total+=int(words[0])

        numreviews+=1
#determine average and if positive or negative or not enough info
if numreviews==0:
    print(word,"appears",numreviews,"times")
    print("There is no average score for reviews containing the word",word)
    print("Cannot determine if this word is positive or negative")
else:
    print(word,"appears",numreviews,"times")
    print("Total score was:",total)
    print("Average score for this word is:",total/numreviews)

    if total/numreviews>=2:
        print("This is a POSITIVE word!")
    else:
        print("This is a NEGATIVE word!")


#set up an empty dictionary to hold all words
words={}

#import time
import time

t=time.time()
print("Initializing sentiment database")

#open up all of movie reviews
file=open("movie_reviews.txt","r")

alldata=str.lower(file.read())

file.close()

splitreviews=alldata.split("\n")

total=0
for review in splitreviews:

    word=review.split(" ")

    #examine every word in this review
    #add it to the sentiment dictionary if necessary
    #or update it if it already exists
    for w in word:

        if w not in words: 
            #add it to the dictionary!
            words[w]=[int(word[0]),1]
            total+=1

        else:
            #update the word using the new review
            words[w][1]+=1
            words[w][0]+=(str(word[0]))

#all done

print("Sentiment database initialization complete")
print("Total unique words analyzed:",total)
print("Analysis took",time.time()-t,"seconds to complete")


phrase=str.lower(input("Enter a phrase to test: "))

phraseparts=phrase.split(" ")

totalaverage=0
num=0

#iterate over each element of phrase pulling info from dictionary
for p in phraseparts:
    if p not in words:
        print("*",p,"does not appear in any movie reviews")  
    else:
        num+=1
        print("*",p,"appears",words[p][1],"times with an average score of",words[p][0]/words[p][1])
        totalaverage+=words[p][0]/words[p][1]

if num==0:
    print("Not enough words to determine sentiment.")

#determine average if words in the phrace appear in the dictionary
else:
    print("Average score for this phrase is: ",totalaverage/num)

#determine if it's a positive or negative word
    if totalaverage/num>=2:
        print("This is a POSITIVE phrase")
    else:
        print("This is a NEGATIVE phrase")
```

For reference the file moviereviews.txt looks like this:

```
1 A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story .  
4 This quiet , introspective and entertaining independent is worth seeking .    
1 Even fans of Ismail Merchant 's work , I suspect , would have a hard time sitting through this one .  
3 A positively thrilling combination of ethnography and all the intrigue , betrayal , deceit and murder of a Shakespearean tragedy or a juicy soap opera .  
1 Aggressive self-glorification and a manipulative whitewash .  
4 A comedy-drama of nearly epic proportions rooted in a sincere performance by the title character undergoing midlife crisis .  
1 Narratively , Trouble Every Day is a plodding mess .  
3 The Importance of Being Earnest , so thick with wit it plays like a reading from Bartlett 's Familiar Quotations  
1 But it does n't leave you with much . 
1 You could hate it for the same reason .
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a **minimal sample** instead of all the code (see [mcve]). What exactly is `word[0]` when it throws the `ValueError`?

Comment: Catch the exception and print the word you are trying to cast to an int. I bet it's the last line that crashes because it's empty.

Comment: The error line referred to at the top is *not* included in the code

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit hard to help you with the information I have so here is a working example of what I think you are trying to do.

```
string = "This movie sucks so badly, it is the worst thing I have seen in my entire life"

score = 0

positive = ["good", "best", "happy", "happiest", "amazing", "perfect"]
negative = ["bad", "worst", "sad", "saddest", "stupid", "disgusting"]

words = string.split(" ")

for i in words:
    if any(i in item for item in positive):
        score += 1

    if any(i in item for item in negative):
        score -= 1

if score == 0:
    print("Not enough words to determine sentiment")

if score > 0:
    print("Happy with a score of:", score)
else:
    print("Sad with a score of:", score)
```

I know this question is very old but other people may need this.